# Throw Not found instead of Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have app URL `127.0.0.1:8000`. Whatever I put after this URL, Laravel returns this error. For example: `127.0.01:8000/asfs` or `<img src="{{ asset('public/image.png') }}">`

> Trying to get property of non-object

What I want is Laravel should return **Not Found** error instead of **Trying to get property of...**. Are there any better ways?

**My Route**

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'ViewController@view')->name('view')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
Route::post('/login', 'Admin\AuthsController@login');
```

**View**

```
<p>
<img alt="Home" src="{{ asset('public/logo.png')}}"/>
</p>
```

**ViewController**

```
public function view($url)
{
    $pr = Pr::where('url', $url)->first();

    return view ('show', compact('pr'));

}
```

Comment: post more code, what is the route pointing to?

Comment: @SapneshNaik I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is typical to trying to retrieve a data that is not available in the database. Ensure that whatever data you want to retrieve, be it a picture or any data at all has been persisted in the database.  Then try retrieving the data again.

You can try this

```html
if ( $pr->ul){

return view ('show', compact('pr'));

}else{

    return view ('errors.404');

}
```

Comment: Why it shows `Trying to get property...` for random links like `127.0.0.1:8000/asdf`?

Comment: Can I see your Viewcontroller

Comment: I know `Route::get('/{url}', 'ViewController@view')` is throwing `Trying to get property...` for random links. How to restrict other variables to this route?

Comment: what is this Pr ? you are getting this error because the $url parameter for $p   hasn't been registered in the database already. Check to ensure. And I think you need to write a condition statement. if the url is null or not the one in the database, redirect to a 404 page.

Comment: Pr is a model. `$p->url` has value `page-url` in database. I want to allow only `page-url` at `127.0.0.1:8000/page-url`. How would I check & redirect to 404, if no value in database?